# In which C*-algebras one-sided-invertible elements are invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

For matrices $AB=I$ is equivalent to $BA=I$, however this is no longer true for operators on infinite-dimensional spaces. I was wondering whether there was a characterisation of C*-algebras where similar phenomena takes place.

What would be sufficient conditions for a Banach algebra to make it work too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a $C^{\ast}$ algebra $A$, we say that a project $p\in A$ is *infinite* if it is Murray Von Neumann equivalent to a proper subprojection of itself. ie. $\exists v\in A$ such that $vv^{\ast} = p$, and $v^{\ast}v < p$.

If $A$ is unital with unit $1_A$, we say that $A$ is *finite* if $1_A$ is not infinite. If $A$ is non-unital, we say $A$ is finite, if its unitization is finite.

As it turns out the following are equivalent for a unital $C^{\ast}$ algebra $A$

1. $A$ is finite
2. All isometries are unitary.
3. All projections in $A$ are finite.
4. Every left invertible element is invertible (the condition you want).
5. Every right invertible element is invertible.

---

For a Banach algebra, I don't know if there is any characterization for this. However, there is a sufficient condition. If the Banach algebra has left (or right) topological stable rank one [See [this paper](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimipfVpa7TAhVKPo8KHWBTAe0QFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.univie.ac.at%2Fnuhag-php%2Fbibtex%2Fopen_files%2F2079_Rieffel-StableRank.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGs2urkpd5PDoon-fRrKjD1Ct68lA) by Rieffel], then any left invertible element is invertible.